# User-defined functions vs. Built-in / Pre-defined functions

Tags: function, methods, user-defined-functions, built-in

Which is more preferable? between the two? like for example in sorting arrays, would it be more **practical** to use **pre-defined sorting function** than creating **your own sorting function?**

---

## What are the advantages and disadvantages between using a Pre-defined Function and User-defined function?

Comment: is it just ok to use the pre defined function without having any, or little idea on how its done?

Comment: If you have to code fast and `error proof` the answer could be Yes, but most of the time the answer would be No. See my answer bellow.

Comment: I know, I just used 3 times the word `answer` in the same sentence. This could probably be factorized. An optimization would somehow be required here. May be a built-in function can do it, but would it give me a nicest or even an understandable result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, pre-defined functions are better, if they exist. They usually are optimized to operate in the least amount of time, no matter what the input (they optimize based on input type and size). Really, the only reason you should user-define something is if the functionality of the pre-defined code does not meet some certain requirement that you have. For example, there may be a search function that has been pre-defined and returns a boolean, but you need to know the index of the found item.

Long story short: **it's often best to use pre-defined if it's defined**.

Answer (score 1):

Only use user defined functions if the pre defined function doesn't meet your need for a "very good" reason. Never good to reinvent the wheel

Comment: is it just ok to use the pre defined function without having any, or little idea on how its done?

Answer (score 1):

A diligent programmer always tries to know how built-in functions are implemented. For the reason that he's got to choose among multiple solutions every time and has to make the best choice to fit his needs. Moreover, to know if coding his own feature is pertinent or not compared to existing ones.

Most of the time built-in functions are optimized for the best, but sometimes you will need more accurate or faster implementation, and will have to do your own version.

**Example :** If you need to compute the intersection between two `std::set` of integers (C++ STL), you will get very poor performance on large sets. If computing fast is your priority better write your own representation of a set. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15042999/1715716) is a sample case where I had to do such a thing.

**Note :** As mentioned by TGH, it is `Never good to reinvent the wheel`. So before implementing your own feature, you should also try to find out if a qualitative third party library as not already been written (taking care of the license requirements, of course). Such that you can use it directly, or get some inspiration from it.

Answer (score 0):

A built in function is a predefined function or statement or operator that supplied along with compiler used i c program.
while user defined function is a self contained building blocks of statement which are written by the user to compute the value or to program a task, they can be called by the main function as per requirement of the called function.